# Dealing with colinearity and if and how interaction terms could improve regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, multicollinearity

In the last months, I'm working on estimating a logistic and multinomial regression model to analyze the relationship of students characteristics and the chances to dropout of school. For example, I'm trying to understand the impact of income, color/ethnicity, sex etc. in the probability for the individual to decide to abandon studies. But I'm also looking at some other variables referent to the educational trajectories, for example, if the student received some type of social benefit or participated in an extra-curricular activity.

This brings us to the problem I'm facing: I found that there is a high colinearity with the color/ethnicity of a student, specifically black students, to receive or not some type of benefit or participate in external activities.

So when I run the model (logistic or multinomial), the chances of a black student to dropout are highly elevated compared to the chances when I don't insert these variables in the model (social benefit and activity).

Remembering some of my linear regression classes and reading some statistics texts, I thought about inserting interactive terms with theses variables in the model in order to improve it. It actually returned to "normal" behaviour, but I'm not quite sure if this is the correct path to take and why exactly inserting interaction terms impact the model coefficients in this way. I can't really exclude the variables because they are very important to my analysis.

So my question is: is correct to insert interaction terms to deal with colinearity between variables and, if so, how exactly it deals with colinearity in regression models?

I'm working this dataset with R, using packages like glm and nnet.

Comment: Including additional terms--whether interactions or not--cannot decrease collinearity; it can only increase it.

Comment: Sure, but my question is more about the interpretation of the coefficients. I don't think that the collinearity is gone, but after I included interaction terms between the two variables that have high collinearity, the coefficients of the variables changed to "normal" values. As I want to understand better the specific effects of all my variables, I wanted to know if this makes sense.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.